# textarea fit parents width minus margins

Tags: html, css, layout, textarea

I'm sure that is a very common question but I am unable to find my simple situation in previous answers....

I have a `textarea` inside a `div`

Imagine that `div` has a `width` of `90%` of its container and I would like that `textarea` spans across the entire `width` of `div` `.notes` minus a left, right `margin` of `10px`

Something like `100%` of `div - 10px` of `left` `margin` `10px` of `right` `margin`")

```
<div class="notes">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <button>Save</button>
</div>
```

Obviously the solution could be very useful also for every other `div` inside a `div` for which we want to set a `width` in a similar way.... How to obtain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```
textarea {
    width: calc(100% - 20px); /* 20px = 10px for left and 10px for right */
    margin: auto; /* To horizontally center your textarea */
    display: block; /* Required for horizontally centering as well*/
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/abA67/)

---

Note: If you are conscious about the legacy browsers, make sure you use `-webkit-calc` and `-moz-calc` as well.

There are some js polyfills, like:

- [Calc-Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
- [Polycalc](http://jsfiddle.net/abA67/)

Comment: I didn't know this property and this is fantastic. I think that I'll use it very often in the future instead of simple % sizes....
I'm using it in restricted access area of my site, so.... I think that use of modern browser could be an acceptable constraint! :-)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use as well box-sizing and a padding instead a margin:

```
div {
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;/*includes border & padding */
  background:gray;
}
textarea {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;/*includes border & padding */
}
```

DEMO http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uegjo

Comment: Well, this is a better way too, but no, this shouldn't be the solution, you are modifying the parent to accomodate `textarea`, there can be other elements too.. so shouldn't do this :)

Comment: i do not modify parent, as I said I send margin to padding and use box-sizing to include it in parents width . Lets OP says what he thinks about it and what he can dowith these CSS behaviors :)

Comment: Ans it depends on what browser he still want to support. if he sticks to modern Browsers, the calc will be fine. Otherwise you need the other way.

Comment: anyhow, a crossbrowser including the oldest ones :) solution will go with javascript. no need to comment about box-sizing nor calc() but we must use them to see them fully usable in futur :). i never think there is a best a worse solution, there's if you are lucky, options